# Run second entry point from same java program in same or new process

Tags: java, javafx, libgdx, game-engine

For a school assignment I am making a desktop game in java. Using a game engine this would be easy enough the only problem is I have to use javaFX and since javaFX hijacks the the main entry-point of the application it would be nearly impossible to combine javaFX with a game engine like lets say LibGDX. So I was wondering would it be possible to run a second entry point from the first javaFX application with the game engine to be able to still use javaFX as a GUI?

Comment: You mean like have 2 `main()`s?  I don't think that's possible, but I have a hard time believing that javaFX doesn't have some equivalent.

Comment: the thing is there are tons of alternatives to javafx the problem however is that I am forced to use javaFX on this project by school

Comment: javaFX seemingly has an "entry point".  According to the JavaDocs, there is an `init()` method that gets called first to allow you to initilize things, then a `start()` method that is called to actually start the program.  Why can you not use one of them?  For reference, this is where I found it:  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html

Comment: I have seen, that you can start an lwjgl game inside a JFrame: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253405/how-to-put-properly-a-libgdx-application-inside-swing-application
I think it should go with JavaFX to.