# Libgdx with Java Swing issue

Tags: java, swing, libgdx, lwjgl

I have a problem with libgdx. I want to use Screen from libgdx to draw game inside JPanel (from Swing, because my all app is written in Swing). I've tried, but I cannot do that.
Is it possible? Have you got any code examples?

Please for help and sorry for my english (just in case).

Comment: not entirely similar, but check if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21258666/3998458) helps you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21258666

It uses LWJGLCanvas to embed libGDx inside a JPanel